# Landscape scripting - access denied when trying to copy files

Tags: bash, scripts, landscape

I'm using Landscape to manage 7 PCs and I'm having an issue where I try to copy files over from my admin account to a non-admin account (called internet).

When I tried using the admin account to copy the file over (I'm trying to create a bash script which will create 5 url shortcuts on the desktop) but when I do, I get access denied. I can't do it with the non-admin account either because it don't have rights being a standard user.

I can `ssh` and use `sudo` for each PC but I want to use Landscapes scripts functionality so I can add and remove files as I need to to multiple PCs with one set of clicks.

I have some bash experience but it's all very basic and I am not sure how to set up this script without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely scenario is that when you originally set up your Landscape clients, you did not give them the permission to execute scripts.

You should re-run the setup of each Landscape client, granting the ability to run scripts as root.

Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure landscape-client`